# use nginx as load balancer for multiple mail servers

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, mail-server

I'm trying to use Nginx as load balancer for mail servers if mail server went down let me send the email through the other i need example for nginx.conf at least two mail servers are running.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has a tcp proxy module (https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/).

```
    tcp {

            upstream cluster {
                # simple round-robin
                server 192.168.0.1:80;
                server 192.168.0.2:80;

                check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
            }

            server {
                listen 8888;

                proxy_pass cluster;
            }
        }
```

Also you can use haproxy.

Comment: Thanks Valery but i want to load balance between mail servers using nginx mail module not web servers can you advise?

Comment: Set necessary port and then test it on test platform. Why not use simple DNS round-robin? Just add multiple MX records with the same weight, pointing to a set of hosts that can receive the email.

Comment: any idea how to send emails through postfix or exim without authentication ?